# Linear programming: division of variable by the sum of the same variable

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, ampl

I have a problem with the linearisation of my code. I have an expression such as

[image: fraction]

(unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post an image (or formula), so I will write it in math mode

```
\frac{F_t}{\sum_t F_t \cdot c_t}
```

or

```
F_t/(sum_t F_t * c_t)
```

with `Ft>=0` being variables and `ct>=0` a constant.

Is there a possibility to approximate this expression (ideally trace out `Ft`)

Comment: If and how to linearize depends on the details.

Comment: What do you mean by level of detail?
`Ft` is a variable changing its value for 10 different time steps `>=0`, `ct` varies between 0 and 1.

Comment: Things depend on how this expression exactly appears in the constraints or objective. And reformulations also depend on the solver capabilities.

Comment: The constraint is
`var1 = Ft/(sum_t Ft*ct)`
with `var1 >= 0` being another variable

I'm using AMPL with the solvers CPLEX or Gurobi

Comment: This is a very strange constraint. I doubt this is correct. As `var1` is a scalar variable, all `F(t)` have to be the same. This does not make sense at all. I suggest discussing this problem with your teacher or supervisor as there are some problems with how the problem is stated.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot the temporal aspect of `var1_t`
Let's therefore formulate it differently:
`Ft/(sum_t Ft*ct) = At/(sum_t At*ct)`

Comment: This can be formulated as a non-convex quadratic constraint. This can be solved with MINLP solvers like Couenne, Baron or with a quadratic solver like Gurobi.